# How do I make my Discord bot join specific servers? The bot requires a paid subscription and I don't want the invite link to be leaked

Tags: javascript, bots, discord, discord.js

I want my Discord bot to only be added to servers where the owner has paid for a subscription. When I give them the bot invite link, I don't want the link to be leaked so how would I fix this problem?

Comment: Explain what you tried exactly and expected results!

Comment: @deoncagadoes: That advice is not meaningful for a "how do I do such-and-such" question rather than a "why doesn't it work" question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the "Requires OAuth2 Code Grant" slider in the "bot" tab of the application configuration, and set `grant_type` to `authorization_code` in the authorization link you give to your customer.

Then you get an Oauth2 redirection to your backend code, with additional `guild_id` and `permissions` querystring parameters that tells you which guild they're trying the add the bot to. The bot will only *actually* be joined if you choose to go through the token exchange after the callback, which you could decide for example based on a `state` parameter in the authorization URL, or your own login cookies or whatever.

This is documented at https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/topics/oauth2#advanced-bot-authorization

---

For a poor man's version that doesn't require implementing the client part of Oauth2 at your end, you could also just make the bot *spontaneously leave* any guild it is not prepared to be in.